# How can I extend Racket's reader for better path handling?

Tags: racket

I've been working on converting a static site generator that I wrote in Python to Racket. This is primarily a learning exercise to get to know Racket better. I've now got the Racket version working, but there is one thing that I like much better about the Python version: the `pathlib.Path` object. The generator has a lot of path handling, which looks like this in the Python code:

```
render_template(root / "templates" / "index.jinja")
```

Whereas the Racket code looks more like this:

```
(render-template (build-path (root) "templates" "index.jinja"))
```

I find the ability to read paths much cleaner in the Python code, so I'd like to modify the Racket reader to be able to support something like the following:

```
(render-template (root) / "templates" / "index.jinja")
```

Playing around with readers, I figured out how to make this kind of expression work:

```
(render-template  / foo / templates / index.jinja /)
```

I'd be OK with the syntax, but I can't figure out how to evaluate the path elements as Racket expressions and not just strings. Even if I did figure that out, I still have the issue that naive string handling would cause problems with something like:

```
(render-template / (root) / (string-join 
                             (list "templates" "subdir") "/") 
                 / "index.jinja" /)
```

So, any advice/input on what I can do here? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, originally you had something like this:

```
(define (root)
  "/")

(define (render-template path)
  (displayln path))

(render-template (build-path (root) "templates" "index.jinja"))
;; => /templates/index.jinja
```

What I suggest is simply changing `render-template` so that it may be
called with multiple path "parts" -- and it handles calling
`build-path` for you:

```
(define (render-template . path-parts)
  (define path (apply build-path path-parts))
  (displayln path))
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
(render-template (root) "templates" "index.jinja")
;; => /templates/index.jinja
```

Incidentally, calling it the original way still works, because
`build-path` will act as identity in this case:

```
(render-template (build-path (root) "templates" "index.jinja"))
;; => /templates/index.jinja
```

I think this is the most "Rackety" way. One nice thing about
s-expressions is you don't have to type "separators" like `,` or `/`.
Spaces suffice. And I think the more you read and write Racket code,
the more you'll feel this way.

Granted, perhaps the most Rackety thing of all is the ability to make
your own little (or big) languages. If you wanted a "DSL" to write
files consisting primarily of paths, that might be one thing. But in
this case I'm not sure I see the big win.

---

If anything, *maybe* you want just a macro
that makes `/` act as whitespace in this context. i.e. To 
make `/` mean the "nothing" that it ultimately needs to be, in the expanded code.

For example:

```
#lang racket/base

(require (for-syntax racket/base syntax/parse))

(define-syntax (render-template stx)
  (define-splicing-syntax-class pp
    (pattern (~seq part (~optional (~literal /)))))
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ p:pp ...) #'(do-render-template p.part ...)]))

(define (do-render-template . path-parts)
  (define path (apply build-path path-parts))
  (displayln path))

(render-template (root) / "templates" / "index.jinja")
;; => /templates/index.jinja
(render-template (root) "templates" "index.jinja")
;; => /templates/index.jinja
```

Note that the `/` are completely optional here. They get treated as
whitespace.

Also note that the real work is done in the function, renamed now to `do-render-template`. The macro is just a wrapper. Generally it's best for macros to do as little work as necessary, and for things that *can* be functions to be functions.

But again, personally I wouldn't bother with the macro, I'd go with the approach I suggested above.

---

*Update*: As a p.s., if I understand correctly, Python's `PathLib.Path` is defining `/` as an operator? Well, Racket doesn't really have "operators". It has functions. And the math functions like `/` accept any number of arguments. So instead of `10 / 5 / 2` we write `(/ 10 5 2)`.  Which, really, brings us full-circle back to `build-path`: A function that takes any number of path parts.

I suppose you could effectively rename `build-path` to `/`:

```
(require (rename-in (except-in racket /)
                    [build-path /]))
(/ (root) "templates" "index.jinja")
```

But this isn't really operator overloading, because these are plain functions not methods. And... I wouldn't do it. :)

Comment: I was afraid the single call to `render-template` would cause this confusion. If it were just `render-template`, I wouldn't care at all, but it is dozens of functions involving various paths.

Now, the syntax at the end gives me some ideas on a way to accomplish this.

Comment: So I decided to play around with the `define-syntax` option and am getting an error: 
    paths.rkt:9:18: syntax: unbound identifier in the transformer environment;
    ;  also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound
    ;   at: syntax
    ;   in: (syntax (do-create-path p.part ...))

Comment: Arg. I've been using `#lang racket/base` for everything, since it's a script I'm writing. Apparently, `#lang racket/base` is missing something this wants.

Comment: With `#lang racket/base` you may need `(require (for-syntax racket/base))`. If that doesn't help, then it's probably worth making a fresh StackOverflow question for that, and/or posting on the Racket mailing list, and/or asking on #racket IRC.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the guidance and for helping me learn Racket a little more.